# Get attribute of JQuery ui.draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I'm using JqueryUI for drag and drop on one of my pages and for some reason I can't seem to get an attribute of the ui.draggable object being passed into my droppable drop event.

ui.draggable.attr("src") and $(ui.draggable).attr("src") both return undefined, however if I type ui.draggable.html() I will get the html back.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you naming your second argument to drop() 'ui'?  So:

`drop:function(event,ui){...`

Comment: Yep,  drop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.draggable.attr("src"));
    }

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out.  The solution is to call ui.draggable.find("img").attr("src"), I just assumed that the ui.draggable object was an image.

Answer (score 2):

@Jon's answer is correct. The solution is just simply try `attr` method, without trying to  inspect the draggable element beforehand ( otherwise you will be puzzled).

given a html element declared as jQuery UI's 'draggable':

```
<img src='some/path/for/this/image' class='draggable_img' title='I am an image!' />
```

and given this 'div' as droppable:

```
<div id='droppable_area'> </div>

<script>
$('img.candidate_thumbnail').droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    console.info('ui.draggable.title:' + ui.draggable.title);
    console.info('ui.draggable.attr("title"):' + ui.draggable.attr('title'));
    console.dir('ui.draggable:' + ui.draggable);
  }    
</script>
```

And I got :

```
ui.draggable.title: undefined
ui.draggable.attr("title"): I am an image!
ui.draggable: [object Object]
  -> No Properties
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this way, for example

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>New Web Project</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>          
        <style>         
        body{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        .box{
            display:block;
            width:100px;
            height:50px;
            background-color:green;
            border:1px solid #000;
        }

        #drop{
            position:absolute;
            top:220px;
            left:220px;
            width:250px;
            height:250px;
            border:1px solid red;
            background:yellow;
            z-index:1;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#boxBesar p').each(function(index,element){
                $('#boxBesar p:eq('+index+')').css({
                    'border':'1px solid #000',
                    'width':'100px',
                    'height':'100px',
                    'position':'absolute',
                    'left':(index*200)+10,
                    'z-index':index+2,
                    'color':'black',
                    'text-align':'center',
                    'background':'#ccc'
                })
            })

                    .draggable({
                        revert:true
                    })

            $('#drop').droppable({
                    drop:dropIt
            })

            function dropIt(event,ui){
                            //get an id
                **var id=ui.draggable.attr('id')**

                            //test an id name
                alert(id)
            }

        })
        </script>
    </head>


    <body>
        <div id="boxBesar">
            <p id="b1">Box 1</p>
            <p id="b2">Box 2</p>
        </div>

        <div id="parent">
            <div id="drop" >

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is left for future users. just console log one by ui.draggable and expand it, then ui.draggable.context ...... so on. You will understand whatthe source name is.

```
console.log(ui.draggable.context.attributes.src.textContent)
```